# Handler not updating ActionBar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title, android-handler

I am writing code for a music player and everything seems to be working fine except the ActionBar. When a song is playing, a thread probes the service every second for a change in the song and if there is a change in the song, a handler object changes the UI elements.

```
final Handler uiHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle data = msg.getData();
        song = data.getParcelable("song_info");
        songText.setText(song.getSongTitle());
        artistText.setText(song.getSongArtist());
        seekBar.setMax(mService.getDuration()/1000); //All these work
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mService.getSongName()); //Not updating
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

What this does is when there is a message from the thread, it updates the UI. I can confirm that this works and is invoked when I need it to. All the text views and the seekbar get updated as required. However, the getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...) doesn't update the title bar.
The same method of setting action bar title works if I do it in other methods of the same class. Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance!
**Update:**
Here's some more code that the Activity has, in case it helps strike something.

```
 private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
                MusicService.MusicBinder mBinder = (MusicService.MusicBinder)iBinder;
                mService = mBinder.getService();
                pauseBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
                seekBar.setMax(mService.getDuration()/1000);
                CounterThread cThread = new CounterThread();
                Thread counter = new Thread(cThread);
                counter.start();
                if(mService.isPaused()) {
                    pauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_36dp);
                }
                else {
                    pauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_36dp);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            }
        };

        private class CounterThread implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        if(!mService.getSongName().equals(song.getSongTitle())) //This is invoked when there is a change in the song.{
                            Message msg = uiHandler.obtainMessage();
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putParcelable("song_info", mService.getSong());
                            msg.setData(b); //I receive this message in the handler
                            uiHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                        }
                        seekBar.setProgress(mService.getCurrPosn()/1000);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song_playing);
        song = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("song_info");
        songText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songname);
        artistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artistname);
        songText.setText(song.getSongTitle());
        artistText.setText(song.getSongArtist());
        header = getSupportActionBar();
        seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
                mService.seek(progress*1000);
            }
        });

        assert header != null;
        header.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        header.setCustomView(R.layout.head_layout);
        titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        titleText.setText(song.getSongTitle());

    }
/* 
More operations
*/
public void next(View v) {
        mService.nextSong();
        pauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_36dp);

        assert header != null;
        header.setTitle(mService.getSongName());  // This works fine

        songText.setText(mService.getSongName());
        artistText.setText(mService.getArtistName());
        titleText.setText(mService.getSongName());
        seekBar.setMax(mService.getDuration()/1000);
    }
```

Don't mind the slight indentation offset.

Comment: Just out of interest, what happens if you use  `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(song.getSongTitle())` instead?

Comment: what moment do you create the Handler and what moment do you send it a Message?

Comment: @clownba0t Tried that as well. No difference, same issue!

Comment: @nandsito The handler object is created when a class object is created but it is only invoked when the song changes (that is when I frame a message object with the song details and send it to the ui handler, since I'm invoking it in a thread I made that's responsible for ticking every second). It works perfectly fine for the other UI elements and the result I get is as required - Text changes when the song autoswitches to the next track. It's kinda weird. :/

Comment: Hmmm. What exactly does `mService.getSongName()` return when it's called (perhaps try logging the value)? Also, I don't suppose you're setting the title of the action bar anywhere else?

Comment: @clownba0t It returns the song name as intended. And no, this is where I am setting the title of the action bar. Other than this, there is the oncreate function where I set it, but that's completely independent

Comment: Yikes, this is a tough one. Would you mind posting the rest of the code for the activity that the snippet above is from?

Comment: @clownba0t I have added a significant amount of code corresponding to that activity. There are a few more methods but they shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks! What's in the custom layout you're setting on the action bar?